# How do I display build outputs of several remote Jenkins Servers in a master Jenkins Server?

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration

We use 6 Jenkins Servers running builds of Six different modules. How can I pull outputs of all the builds in the 6 Jenkins Servers into a consolidated view in a Master Jenkins Server? The ultimatum is to have a single interface to monitor all jobs.

Answer (score 0):

So just for the terminology:

- one jenkins master can have multiple slaves
- the build result of a job will always be displayed on the master
- two different jenkins master are not visible to each other

This means:

- You need one jenkins master
- To display the result of different jobs on one Dashboard you can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View
- consider to integrate the build of all modules in one pipeline https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/, then you don't have to use the Dashboard View